# If statement JAVA

Tags: java, if-statement

```
int num=6;
num=num+1;
if (num>6)
jTextField1.setText(Integer.toString(num));
else
jTextField1.setText(Integer.toString(num+5));
```

**I am confused with the output which will be displayed in jTextField1 if it should be 12 or 11**.

*My one more question,*
in the below case what would we use "num=7" or "num==7"?

```
int num=6;
if (num==7)
jTextField1.setText("a");
else
jTextField1.setText("b");
```

Comment: For your first question - you could try running the code to see what it does.

Comment: "I am confused with the output" - What do you get when you run your code?

Comment: Please help me with the second question I am really confused.

Comment: int num=Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText);

Comment: if (num==10) or if (num=10) which is correct?

Comment: `(num == 10)` is correct.

Comment: I strongly suggest working your way through the online Java tutorials provided by Oracle.  These questions are fairly elementary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You refer the below code with comments:

```
int num=6;//num is 6 here
num=num+1;//num is 7 after this step
if (num>6)//num is greater than 6 ? YES, so below line will be executed
jTextField1.setText(Integer.toString(num));//It comes here & sets jTextField1 as 7
else
jTextField1.setText(Integer.toString(num+5));
```

In the first case as explained above, `jTextField1` will be set as 7.

> What would we use "num=7" or "num==7"?

`num=7` is assignment of 7 to `num` variable

`num==7` is used when you are checking a condition for `num` is 7 which simply returns `true` or `false` (you need to note that, `==` is equality operator in Java which is used to check if two values are equal or not)

> I want to know if we use if(num==7) or if(num=7) ?

You never use `num=7` during the condition check of `if` , `while` or `for`

I suggest you read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) and understand the basics first.

Comment: When you say "NO" do you mean yes?

Comment: good spot, I mean YES

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to know if we use if(num==7) or if(num=7)?

Comment: downvoters, it would be really good if you take time to comment on what's missing

Comment: We need to use `num==7` inside `if` condition (or any condition checking)

Comment: Also, go through the above link to understand the operators in Java

Answer (score 0):

I've added some comments to your code to explain the meanings of the statements:

```
int num=6; // the variable named "num" is declared an int and assigned the value 6
num=num+1; // the int "num" is assigned the value 7
if (num>6)   // 7 > 6 (true_
jTextField1.setText(Integer.toString(num)); // 7 displayed by jTextField1
else
jTextField1.setText(Integer.toString(num+5)); // not evaluated since 7 > 6
```

And for the second question:

`num = 7` means the value `7` is assigned to the variable `num`.
`num == 7' returns a true/false depending on the value of`num`.